# Exercise: conditional probability, joint probability, and law of total probability (#63, Chapter 2, Devore and Berk, 2nd edition)

Tags: probability, self-learning, conditional-probability

This question is #63 in Chapter 2 of Modern Mathematical Statistics with Applications by Jay Devore and Kenneth Berk (Page 84, 2nd edition).

A professional organization sells term life insurance and medical
insurance.

- Of those who have just life insurance, 70% will renew next year
- Of those who have just medical insurance, 80% will renew next year
- Of those who have both types of insurance, 90% will renew at least one of them next year.

Of the policy holders

- 75% have term life insurance
- 45% have major medical
- 20% have both

a. Calculate the percentage of policyholders that
will renew at least one policy next year.

b. If a randomly selected policy holder does in
fact renew next year, what is the probability
that he or she has both life and major medical
insurance?

---

Here are my attempts to answer the 2 questions.  **Do they look right to you?**

Let

- $L = \text{have life insurance}$
- $M = \text{have medical insurance}$
- $R = \text{will renew the insurance policy next year}$

a) $P(R) = P(R \cap L \cap M^c) + P(R \cap L^c \cap M) + P(R \cap L \cap M)
\\ = P(R | L \cap M^c) * P(L \cap M^c) + P(R | L^c \cap M) * P(L^c \cap M) + P(R | L \cap M) * P(L \cap M)$

$P(L \cap M^c) = P(L) - P(L \cap M) = 0.75 - 0.20 = 0.55$
$P(L^c \cap M) = P(M) - P(L \cap M) = 0.45 - 0.20 = 0.25$

$P(R) = 0.70*0.55 + 0.80*0.25 + 0.90*0.20 = 0.765$

b) $P(L \cap M | R)  = P(L \cap M \cap R) \ \div \ P(R) = 0.90 * 0.20 \ \div \ 0.765 = 0.235$

Comment: Looks right for me.